# Adding physics,mathematics and stackoverflow links in footer

Tags: discussion

It will me easy to access stackexchange science related sites like [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) if we add links of the above sites to the footer of chemistry
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think its by design that the beta sites link to other betas, and the main sites link to other mains. Once the community promotion ads are up, you can cross promote if you wish.